# How to get extra keys to show up on an iPhone keyboard for web input?

Tags: iphone, keyboard

When going to certain web pages with my iPhone, I notice that some text input boxes popup a different keyboard layout.

For example, Hotmail's login page shows a keyboard with a smaller spacebar and an @ key when on the email address field.

How can I control the keyboard layout myself when designing web pages?  I'm not talking about an application, only a normal web page that is designed for an iPhone.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably looking for `<input type="email">`. Here is a [nice list of the input types that mobile browsers support](http://www.quirksmode.org/html5/inputs_mobile.html).

Comment: Thanks. This is what I was looking for.  I was hoping for more control, but I guess this will have to do.